# drupal localhost to domain name in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drupal, apache2

I have installed drupal on my local machine(ubuntu 12.04). It run successfully when I hit http//localhost/drupal. I want to change localhost to mywebsite. I have tried google it  but solution didn't  worked till now. My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/drupal is mentioned below

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Drupal user I highly recommend `Acquia Dev Desktop` as a way of running Drupal. It has many features including naming your domaine.

Comment: Can I do it with Drush? I have already installed drupal, will installing drush over it work?